# npm - error running package.json

Tags: node.js, npm, browserify

I'm learning nodejs and trying to build a simple console app. The app is working. However, when I run the package.json below, so that I can build it and install all dependencies easily, a few errors came up. Looks like it failed to install dependencies because if I installed the dependencies first, there wouldn't be a problem. Does anyone know what's wrong with my package.json?

Thanks.

```
{
  "name": "Testing",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "My Name",
  "description": "testing",
  "scripts": {
    "build-js": "browserify scripts/app.js > scripts/bundle.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "browserify": "*",
    "uniq": "*"
  }
}
```

When i run `npm run build-js`, i got the following errors:

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\node
\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "build-js"
npm ERR! node v0.12.2
npm ERR! npm  v2.7.4
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! Testing@0.0.1 build-js: `browserify scripts/app.js > scripts/bundle.j

npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the Testing@0.0.1 build-js script 'browserify scripts/app.j
> scripts/bundle.js'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the Testing package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     browserify scripts/app.js > scripts/bundle.js
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls Testing
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\vinh.ngo\Desktop\react-play\npm-debug.log
```

My npm-debug.log is

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'build-js' ]
2 info using npm@2.7.4
3 info using node@v0.12.2
4 verbose node symlink C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe
5 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild-js', 'build-js', 'postbuild-js' ]
6 info prebuild-js Testing@0.0.1
7 info build-js Testing@0.0.1
8 verbose unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
9 info Testing@0.0.1 Failed to exec build-js script
10 verbose stack Error: Testing@0.0.1 build-js: `browserify scripts/app.js > scripts/bundle.js`
10 verbose stack Exit status 1
10 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:213:16)
10 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:110:17)
10 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:14:12)
10 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
10 verbose stack     at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
10 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1087:5)
11 verbose pkgid Testing@0.0.1
12 verbose cwd C:\Users\vinh.ngo\Desktop\react-play
13 error Windows_NT 6.1.7601
14 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "build-js"
15 error node v0.12.2
16 error npm  v2.7.4
17 error code ELIFECYCLE
18 error Testing@0.0.1 build-js: `browserify scripts/app.js > scripts/bundle.js`
18 error Exit status 1
19 error Failed at the Testing@0.0.1 build-js script 'browserify scripts/app.js > scripts/bundle.js'.
19 error This is most likely a problem with the Testing package,
19 error not with npm itself.
19 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
19 error     browserify scripts/app.js > scripts/bundle.js
19 error You can get their info via:
19 error     npm owner ls Testing
19 error There is likely additional logging output above.
20 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Do I have to run `npm install` first to install all dependencies before running `npm run build-js`?

Comment: What is in your C:\Users\vinh.ngo\Desktop\react-play\npm-debug.log?

Comment: Hi Suresh, i just added my npm-debug.log

Comment: Remove those dependency entries, and then first run `npm install browserify --save` and `npm install uniq --save`, because it looks like you wrote those by hand and that's not how dependency version numbers work. If you're doing things by hand, you still need to use semver format. So don't do it by hand.

Comment: `*` is a valid value for a dependency version, @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans. Take a look at `npm help json`.

Comment: Is browserify a dependencies of your app.js or is that a devDependencies?

Comment: @Jordan you are technically correct, but `*` is not a version npm will every use itself. (it will use `^major.minor.build`, so that it will never automatically install the next major version, which by semver definition will be incompatible with previous versions)

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling it's the redirection (`>`) that's causing the problem here, either because of the way the command is executed behind the scenes or because the file you're trying to redirect output to already exists.

You should probably use `browserify`'s `--outfile`/`-o` option instead:

```
"scripts": {
    "build-js": "browserify scripts/app.js -o scripts/bundle.js"
},
```

Comment: I tried this before, but it didnt work either. I have to run `npm install` first then `npm run build-js` to get it to work. Not sure if this is the way?

Comment: You have to run `npm install` every time?

Comment: only have to run it once to install all dependencies. After that, because those dependencies are already there, `run build-js` will work.

Comment: Yes, that's how NPM works. If you don't run `npm install` Browserify isn't installed, and if Browserify isn't installed you can't run `browserify` (and neither can `npm run`).